# Performance comparison custom class versus arrays

Tags: android

Is it more performant to create a class

```
public class test {
    private Circle c;
    private String mac;
    private Short abstand;
    private Location ort;

    public test (String mac, Circle c, Short abstand, Location ort){
        this.c = c;
        this.mac = mac;
        this.abstand = abstand;
        this.ort = ort;
    }

     public String erhalteMac()
     {
         return  mac;
     }

    //etc.
}
```

Create an array list by using

```
ArrayList<test> karte = new ArrayList<test>();
```

and adding

```
test t = new test();

t.mac = "...";

karte.add(t);
```

etc.

to then see if there is an object that has a certain property

```
public static boolean hM(ArrayList<object> list, String mac) {
    for (object object2 : list) {
        if (object2.erhalteMac().equals(mac))
        {
            //work with object2 here.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

versus simply creating four arrays for each type and iterating through only the mac array in my case and use the index of the matching mac string in each other array to make changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array method would be a tiny bit faster than the simple List, but

a [HashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) would be a *lot* faster when there are more than a few object instances.

Comment: Interesting. What do you base this statement on?

Comment: From the linked page:  "[...] provides constant-time performance for the basic operations [...]". Both of your implementations would be O(n) performance.